# Hackerrank: Computer Game (max-flow problem with integer factorization)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes, graph

I am working on a [coding challenge from the Hackerrank site](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/computer-game).  Given two equal-length arrays of integers, with values from 2 to 10<sup>9</sup>, find the maximum number of times we can remove a pair (A<sub>i</sub>, B<sub>j</sub>) where A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>j</sub> are not co-prime.

The programming language of my choice is Python2. 
Hackerrank has [timeout of 10 secs](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment) for the Python2 submissions and it is noteworthy that Hackerrank doesn't provide the `numpy` package for the standard challenges.

My current approach is to reduce this problem to well-known Max-Flow problem and solve it using the [Dinic algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/dinic.html).

My Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#!/bin/python

from collections import *


def gen_primes():
    D = {}
    q = 2

    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]

        q += 1


# precompute prime numbers smaller than sqrt(10**9)
prime_gen = gen_primes()
primes = [next(prime_gen) for _ in xrange(3500)]


# enhanced trial division method using precomputed prime numbers
def trial_division(n):
    a = set()

    while n % 2 == 0:
        a.add(2)
        n /= 2

    i = 1
    f = primes[i]

    while f * f <= n:
        if n % f == 0:
            a.add(f)
            n /= f
        else:
            i += 1
            f = primes[i]

    if n != 1:
        a.add(n)

    return a


def bfs(graph, cap_edges, level, s, t):
    queue = deque()
    queue.append(s)

    level[s] = 1

    while queue:
        u = queue.popleft()

        for v, eid, _ in graph[u]:
            if level[v] == 0 and cap_edges[eid] > 0:
                level[v] = level[u] + 1
                queue.append(v)

    return level[t] > 0


def dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, u, s, t):
    if u == t:
        return 1

    adj = graph[u]
    ind = ptr[u]

    i = ind
    n = len(adj)
    while i < n:
        v, eid, eid_b = adj[i]
        ptr[u] = i
        i += 1

        if (level[v] == level[u] + 1) and cap_edges[eid] > 0:
            f = dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, v, s, t)
            if f > 0:
                cap_edges[eid] -= 1
                cap_edges[eid_b] += 1
                return f

    return 0


# solve the max-flow problem using the Dinic algorithm
def max_flow(graph, cap_edges, s, t):
    n = len(graph)
    level = [0] * n
    ptr = [0] * n

    flow = 0
    while bfs(graph, cap_edges, level, s, t):
        f = dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, s, s, t)

        while f > 0:
            flow += f
            f = dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, s, s, t)

        level = [0] * n
        ptr = [0] * n

    return flow


def computer_game(n, A, B):

    start_node = 0
    end_node = 1

    graph = defaultdict(list)
    cap_edges = []
    node_count = 2
    edges_count = 0
    prime_nodes_map = {}

    for value in A:
        current_node = node_count

        graph[start_node].append((current_node, edges_count, edges_count+1))
        cap_edges.append(1)
        graph[current_node].append((start_node, edges_count+1, edges_count))
        cap_edges.append(0)
        edges_count += 2
        node_count += 1

        factors = trial_division(value)

        for p in factors:
            if p not in prime_nodes_map:
                prime_nodes_map[p] = node_count
                node_count += 1

            p_node = prime_nodes_map[p]
            graph[current_node].append((p_node, edges_count, edges_count+1))
            cap_edges.append(1)

            graph[p_node].append((current_node, edges_count+1, edges_count))
            cap_edges.append(0)
            edges_count += 2

    for value in B:
        current_node = node_count

        graph[current_node].append((end_node, edges_count, edges_count+1))
        cap_edges.append(1)

        graph[end_node].append((current_node, edges_count+1, edges_count))
        cap_edges.append(0)
        edges_count += 2
        node_count += 1

        factors = trial_division(value)
        for p in factors:
            if p not in prime_nodes_map:
                prime_nodes_map[p] = node_count
                node_count += 1

            p_node = prime_nodes_map[p]
            graph[p_node].append((current_node, edges_count, edges_count+1))
            cap_edges.append(1)

            graph[current_node].append((p_node, edges_count+1, edges_count))
            cap_edges.append(0)
            edges_count += 2

    result = max_flow(graph, cap_edges, start_node, end_node)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())

    a = map(int, raw_input().rstrip().split())

    b = map(int, raw_input().rstrip().split())

    computer_game(n, a, b)
```

This Python code gets timeout for the last 2 biggest test instances, but I know in fact that I am using the right algorithm because I submitted a C++ solution implementing **the exact same algorithm**, which passes all the test cases with flying colors.

So my question is, can my Python code above be optimized any further?
Did I miss some obvious optimizations?
At this point I am wondering if this challenge can be solved with Python at all...

Here is a large test-case pair which causes timeout:
[input.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bmktuwien/1b5a2db3a0c2803da9d5c886b295b92e/raw/ba53ebbd4c03a2c0895ddb892bc46e7492c63cb8/input.txt)
[output.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bmktuwien/c5c2a04b8f0397f234ad742c4155f34c/raw/ae274c04430c5a3056a3f5883e01108175d557bb/output.txt)

For the comparison, here is my C++ solution which passes all test cases:

> ```cpp
> #include <bits/stdc++.h>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> struct Entry {
>     int node;
>     int eid;
>     int eid_r; };
>
> vector<int> gen_primes(int n) {
>     vector<int> result;
>
>     bool prime[n+1];
>     memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
>
>     for (int p=2; p*p<=n; p++) {
>         if (prime[p]) {
>             for (int i=p*2; i<=n; i += p)
>                 prime[i] = false;
>         }
>     }
>
>     for (int p=2; p<=n; p++) {
>         if (prime[p]) {
>             result.push_back(p);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return result; }
>
> vector<int> factorization(int n, const vector<int>& primes) {
>     vector<int> a;
>
>     if (!(n&1)) {
>         a.push_back(2);
>         n >>= 1;
>
>         while (!(n&1)) {
>             n >>= 1;
>         }
>     }
>
>     int i = 1;
>     int f = primes[i];
>
>     while (f*f <= n) {
>         if (n % f == 0) {
>             a.push_back(f);
>             n /= f;
>
>             while (n % f == 0) {
>                 n /= f;
>             }
>         }
>         f = primes[i++];
>     }
>
>     if (n != 1) {
>         a.push_back(n);
>     }
>
>     return a; }
>
> bool bfs(const vector<vector<Entry>> &graph,
>          vector<int>& cap_edges, vector<int>& level, int s, int t) {
>     queue<int> q;
>     q.push(s);
>     level[s] = 1;
>
>     while (!q.empty()) {
>         int u = q.front();
>         q.pop();
>
>         for (const Entry &e : graph[u]) {
>             if ((level[e.node] == 0) && (cap_edges[e.eid] > 0)) {
>                 level[e.node] = level[u] + 1;
>                 q.push(e.node);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     return level[t] > 0; }
>
> int dfs(const vector<vector<Entry>> &graph,
>         vector<int>& ptr, vector<int>& cap_edges, vector<int>& level,
>         int u, int s, int t) {
>
>     if (u == t) {
>         return 1;
>     }
>
>     for (int i = ptr[u]; i < graph[u].size(); i++) {
>         const Entry& e = graph[u][i];
>         ptr[u] = i;
>
>         if ((level[e.node] == level[u]+1) && (cap_edges[e.eid] > 0)) {
>             int f = dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, e.node, s, t);
>             if (f > 0) {
>                 cap_edges[e.eid] -= f;
>                 cap_edges[e.eid_r] += f;
>                 return f;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     return 0; }
>
> int max_flow(const vector<vector<Entry>> &graph, vector<int>&
> cap_edges,
>              int s, int t) {
>     int n = graph.size();
>     vector<int> level(n, 0);
>     vector<int> ptr(n, 0);
>
>     int flow = 0;
>
>     while (bfs(graph, cap_edges, level, s, t)) {
>         int f;
>         do {
>             f = dfs(graph, ptr, cap_edges, level, s, s, t);
>             flow += f;
>         } while(f > 0);
>
>         fill(level.begin(), level.end(), 0);
>         fill(ptr.begin(), ptr.end(), 0);
>     }
>
>     return flow; }
>
> void solve(int n, const vector<int>& A, const vector<int>& B) {
>     vector<int> primes = gen_primes(32000);
>
>     int start_node = 0;
>     int end_node = 1;
>
>     vector<vector<Entry>> graph(310000);
>     vector<int> cap_edges;
>     int node_count = 2;
>     int edge_count = 0;
>     map<int, int> prime_nodes_map;
>
>     for (int value : A) {
>         int current_node = node_count;
>
>         graph[start_node].push_back({current_node, edge_count, edge_count+1});
>         cap_edges.push_back(1);
>         graph[current_node].push_back({start_node, edge_count+1, edge_count});
>         cap_edges.push_back(0);
>         edge_count += 2;
>         node_count += 1;
>
>         vector<int> prime_factors = factorization(value, primes);
>         for (int p : prime_factors) {
>             auto it = prime_nodes_map.find(p);
>             if (it == prime_nodes_map.end()) {
>                 prime_nodes_map[p] = node_count;
>                 node_count += 1;
>             }
>
>             int p_node = prime_nodes_map[p];
>             graph[current_node].push_back({p_node, edge_count, edge_count+1});
>             cap_edges.push_back(1);
>
>             graph[p_node].push_back({current_node, edge_count+1, edge_count});
>             cap_edges.push_back(0);
>             edge_count += 2;
>         }
>     }
>
>     for (int value : B) {
>         int current_node = node_count;
>         graph[current_node].push_back({end_node, edge_count, edge_count+1});
>         cap_edges.push_back(1);
>
>         graph[end_node].push_back({current_node, edge_count+1, edge_count});
>         cap_edges.push_back(0);
>         edge_count += 2;
>         node_count += 1;
>
>         vector<int> prime_factors = factorization(value, primes);
>         for (int p : prime_factors) {
>             auto it = prime_nodes_map.find(p);
>             if (it == prime_nodes_map.end()) {
>                 prime_nodes_map[p] = node_count;
>                 node_count += 1;
>             }
>
>             int p_node = prime_nodes_map[p];
>             graph[p_node].push_back({current_node, edge_count, edge_count+1});
>             cap_edges.push_back(1);
>
>             graph[current_node].push_back({p_node, edge_count+1, edge_count});
>             cap_edges.push_back(0);
>             edge_count += 2;
>         }
>     }
>
>     cout << max_flow(graph, cap_edges, start_node, end_node) << endl; }
>
> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>     int n;
>     cin >> n;
>
>     vector<int> a;
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>         int val;
>         cin >> val;
>         a.push_back(val);
>     }
>
>     vector<int> b;
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>         int val;
>         cin >> val;
>         b.push_back(val);
>     }
>
>     solve(n, a, b);
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable for the same algorithm to run in over 5 times the equivalent in C/C++. A quick glance at [Julia's benchmarks](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/) shows this to be true.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thank you for your comment. Funny you mention factor 5, because thats exactly the factor between c++ timeout (2 secs) and python timeout (10 secs) on Hackerrank. But in my case, the python code is ca. 10 times slower than c++ equivalent. Thats why I asked the question in the first place to learn how to improve the code further to reach at least factor 5...

Comment: Have you tried caching the results of your `trial_division` function? And checking the cache inside your `n` loop? It seems likely that you would see some hits, but I'm not sure how many.

Comment: @AustinHastings Yes, I tried to memoize the `trial_division` function but the hits were negligible since the input data are uniformly random generated between 2 and 10^9...

Comment: I was hoping you would get memo hits on smaller values of `n`. Too bad.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are [not allowed to change your code anymore](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me why `gen_primes()` is so complicated. The C++ version, which is a straight sieve, is much clearer.

---

There's one red flag in `trial_division`: `/=` is floating point division. Averaging timing runs would obviously be better, but even on a single timing run changing the two `/=` to `//=` drops the run time from 20.5 secs to 16.2 secs.

The iteration in `trial_division` is also unidiomatic. Replacing it with a `for` loop:

```
def trial_division(n):
    a = set()

    while n % 2 == 0:
        a.add(2)
        n //= 2

    for p in primes:
        if p * p > n:
            break

        while n % p == 0:
            a.add(p)
            n //= p

    if n != 1:
        a.add(n)

    return a
```

the time drops to 12.5 secs.

Profiling with `python -m cProfile cr219119.py <cr219119.in` shows that `trial_division` is still by far the bottleneck. The expensive operations are the multiplication and division, and the division is a problem, but we can remove the multiplication with

```
primesWithSquares = [(p, p*p) for p in primes]
```

and changing the loop to

```
    for p, p2 in primesWithSquares:
        if p2 > n:
            break

        while n % p == 0:
            a.add(p)
            n //= p
```

to get down to 10.8 secs.

Finally, using the same trick as the C++ code of doubling up the tests to use a list rather than a set:

```
def trial_division(n):
    a = []

    if n & 1 == 0:
        a.append(2)
        n //= 2
        while n & 1 == 0:
            n //= 2

    for p, p2 in primesWithSquares:
        if p2 > n:
            break

        if n % p == 0:
            a.append(p)
            n //= p
            while n % p == 0:
                n //= p

    if n != 1:
        a.append(n)

    return a
```

I get a running time of 9.4 secs.

---

As far as the rest of the code goes, I find it severely lacking in comments. A lot of the names are quite good (`trial_division` and `computer_game` are the worst exceptions), but I had to reverse engineer the code to figure out what `prime_nodes_map` was about and I still don't fully understand the `graph` data structure. There also seems to be a lot of potential to factor out some of the code involved in the graph construction. Perhaps (untested)

```
def add_edge(u, v, direction):
    graph[u].append((v, edges_count, edges_count+1))
    cap_edges.append(direction)
    graph[v].append((u, edges_count+1, edges_count))
    cap_edges.append(1 - direction)
    edges_count += 2

def new_node():
    node_count += 1
    return node_count - 1

def add_half_graph(values, end_node, direction):
    for value in values:
        current_node = new_node()

        add_edge(end_node, current_node, direction)

        for p in trial_division(value):
            if p not in prime_nodes_map:
                prime_nodes_map[p] = new_node()

            add_edge(current_node, prime_nodes_map[p], direction)

add_half_graph(A, start_node, 1)
add_half_graph(B, end_node, 0)
```

Comment: Interesting. I always assumed something like `a/b`, for `a` and `b` being integers, would use an integer division in Python 2 since the result is type `int`, but the [dis documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_DIVIDE) says it's actually a different op from `//`.

Comment: @AlexV, I should confess that I profiled with Python3, making minor tweaks, because I don't have Python2 on this machine. I may have put my foot in it with the divisions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you so much for your in depth review! Really appreciate it. If I may make some comments about your points: As someone already mentioned, the `/` operator is an integer division in Python 2 if you don't import `__future__.division` (which I didn't). But the caching of the squared prime numbers saves indeed lots of time (about 4 secs on my machine). It never occurred to me that multiplication could be such a performance killer, especially if the results are less than 10^9. Anyway thank you so much and I will try to resubmit the solution with cached prime-squares...

Comment: fyi: I just resubmitted the revised code with cached squared prime numbers but the last 2 test-cases still time out... But I think I'm getting closer

Comment: (Untested and knowing Python likely to be wrong) Given that for each `while n % p == 0: n //= p` you're effectively performing the same calculation twice, if you change it to one `divmod` you may get a performance increase.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, good suggestion, but in practice it seems to be much slower.